# "How do I return the first and last index of a string, into a vector, with C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector

This is a coding problem from Edabit. I am trying to focus on my problem solving skills in C++ specifically.

The problem is to return the first and last index of a char from a string.  For every instance of char c (second argument) in std::string word (first argument), I think I need to push (char c) with push_back to an empty string and return first and last index from that empty string. Or could I simply pull the first and last instance of a character from the original string using 
(for example: `std::string word.being()`)?

I've included some code below in what I have so far. I'm just stuck on how to implement my idea above with syntax. I think I have the right idea, but not sure how to go about doing so. I don't want an answer exactly, just a guide on what to do next.

```
std::vector<int> charIndex(std::string word, char c) {
    std::string newWord = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i){
        std::string size.push_back[i] = newWord;
        //for every instance of char c in std::string word, I need to 
        //push that (char c) to empty string and return first and last index
        if(newWord[i] ==  )
    }
}
```

These are examples of expected results:

```
charIndex("circumlocution", "c") ➞ [0, 8]
The first "c" has index 0, the last "c" has index 8.
charIndex("happy", "h") ➞ [0, 0]
Only one "h" exists, so the first and last index is 0.
```

Comment: So you know std::find

Comment: This assignment is literally two lines of C++ code using `std::find` and placing the `[first, last]` results into something like a `std::pair<int, int>`.  There is no need for loops, a stack, or anything of the sort.

Comment: I think you may find [`std::string::find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) useful. If you read to the bottom of the linked documentation page you'll find links to other useful utilities for solving other parts of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!!

```
vector<int> arr;
arr[0] = word.find_first_of(c);
arr[1] = word.find_last_of(c);
return arr;
```

Thank you all!!

Comment: That's an out of bounds index (undefined behavior). Just do `return {a, b};` where a and b are the values you want

Comment: Or `std::vector<int> charIndex(std::string word, char c) {return {word.find_first_of(c), word.find_last_of(c)};}`. But `vector<int> arr; arr[0] = word.find_first_of(c);` is not correct.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know what an out of bounds is. I will change it to return {a,b};